# Two 20amp breakers tied together

Tags: electrical

I have two 20 amp breakers tied together. One is on the dedicated refrigerator plug the other is for a dedicated GFI circuit. Why? can I remove the tie? I have installed a transfer switch and I don't need the GFI in a power outage to be energized by my generator. I can power something else that is more essential.I have some experiences being a retires Plumbing and HVAC and have seen this before it just did not come into play doing electrical for HVAC.

Comment: Is the GFCI circuit using a receptacle-type or a breaker-type GFCI?

Comment: If they are normal breakers (not GFCI or AFCI), then they are probably feeding a Multi-Wire Branch Circuit where the neutral is shared. If so, code requires that the tie remain in place.

Comment: I installed the switch and determined that they did share a neutral. I left them tied and ran them too tied breakers ( same rating) . One of tied breakers is on a GFI circuit . When tested everything worked correctly. I sometimes type to fast also so I get nutmeal LOL. I have run across this before but it did not affect my HVAC jobs. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

This is why you shouldn't use transfer switches.  Send it back and use a generator interlock instead, if one can be obtained that fits your panel.

What you're looking at there is a Multi-Wire Branch Circuit (MWBC) or shared neutral circuit.  2 hots 1 neutral, so the circuit uses one 12/3 cable to serve two "demi-circuits".  **These cannot play with transfer switches** unless both legs of the MWBC are on the transfer switch *and they they are handle-tied*.

Transfer switches also don't work with GFCI or AFCI breakers - try it.    These incompatibilities are one of several reasons they suck, another being the cost.

You will either need to place the MWBC on the handle-tied circuit on your transfer switch (it must be the correct amperage!) or do not put the MWBC on the transfer switch at all.

This same thing applies to all the MWBCs in your panel, and you will have to search for them - follow every red wire to its cable, and follow that cable's black wire to its breaker - those are another MWBC and need to be handle-tied both in the panel and the transfer switch, if you insist on putting them in a transfer switch.

Are you sure you want a transfer switch?  Most people buy them because they know better than to use a suicide cord, but don't know what the ???? is that goes between generator and panel. The generator salesman is always there with a helpful answer on which they make a $50 commission.

A generator interlock just sits in 2 breaker spaces with a sliding plate between that breaker space and the main breaker.  It allows you to energize any circuit in your panel, and plays well with AFCI, GFCI and MWBCs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had a feeling they shared a neutral so I checked . All ready installed to switch . I did leave the breakers tied and used the two breakers at the switch for them all the others are on single pole 15 amp breakers with their own neutrals. Tested it all and everything works as promised. I never had to deal with this running circuits for my HVAC work mostly cut and dry electrical. Thanks for the information